# Dojo Grid with editable and non-editable cells

Tags: dojo

We are using dojo 1.4.2 in our project. We have a page where we display a dojox.data.EnhancedGrid from ItemFileWriteStore. We have a use case based on the user access, we need to have a column editable for some rows; for rest of the rows this column should be read only.

So what we are looking at is setting the editable:true at the cell level and not at the column level. All the examples I see are set at the column level. Is there a way to set editable at the cell level?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to set any options (such as editable) at the cell level. As far as I can tell, all options can only be set at the column level.